# Trazer select em uma linha com 2 referências

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se há possibilidades de trazer tudo em uma linha com as seguintes tabelas:

```
Pedidos
id
id_produto1
id_produto2
id_produto3


Produtos

id
produto
```

Queria fazer um select que traga a tabela pedidos com o nome dos produtos do lado de cada id_produto em uma linha. Será possivel?

Exemplo

```
id   |    id_produto1   |  produto  |  id_produto2 | produto | id_produto3 | produto

1    |         2        |    arroz   |       3     |  feijão |       4     | Macarrão
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ouver um relacionamento da tabela Pedido com a tabela Produtos, bastaria utilizar a chave estrangeira desse relacionamento, exemplo:

```
SELECT PEDIDOS.ID, PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO1
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO1) AS PRODUTO,
PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO2
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO2) AS PRODUTO_2,
PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO3
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO3) AS PRODUTO_3,
FROM PEDIDOS
```

No caso, Id_Pedido seria a chave estrangeira.

Comment: não existe a coluna id_pedido e sim id_pedido1, id_pedido2 e id_pedido3.

Comment: SELECT PEDIDOS.ID, PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO1
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO1) AS PRODUTO,
PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO2
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO2) AS PRODUTO_2,
PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO3
(SELECT PRODUTOS.PRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE PRODUTOS.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUTO3) AS PRODUTO_3,
FROM PEDIDOS

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `INNER JOIN` das duas tabelas pegando o id_produto da tabela pedidos e id da tabela produtos para resolver o seu problema:

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT PE.ID_PRODUTO
      ,PR.NOME
  FROM PEDIDOS AS PE
 INNER JOIN PRODUTOS AS PR ON PE.ID_PRODUTO = PR.ID
```

Comment: não existe a coluna id_pedido e sim id_pedido1, id_pedido2 e id_pedido3.

Comment: @RomarioPires então edite seu código colocando as colunas corretas.

Comment: Mas está correto.